# Mybatis results declaration reuse

Tags: java, annotations, mybatis

Following code is working mapper class but it has copypast of resultset declaration (which is huge in my case).
How could I reuse @Results declaration?

```
@Mapper
public interface DailyMasterCurrentTradeDao {
    @Select("select * from dly_mstr_curr_trd")
    @Results({
        @Result(property = "accAdsStC", column = "ACC_ADS_ST_C"),
        ...
    })
    List<DailyMasterCurrentTrade> selectDailyMasterCurrentTrades();

    @Select("select * from dly_mstr_curr_trd where rownum < #{rownumThreshold}")
    @Results({
        @Result(property = "accAdsStC", column = "ACC_ADS_ST_C"),
        ...
    })
    List<DailyMasterCurrentTrade> selectFewDailyMasterCurrentTrades(long rownumThreshold);
}
```

Comment: Please change selected answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use @ResultMap to reference/reuse another @Results definition.

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM user where id = ${value}")
@ResultMap("userResult")
User findOne(Long id);

@Select("SELECT * FROM user")
@Results(id = "userResult", value = {
    @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true),
    @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
    @Result(property = "phone", column = "phone")
})
List<User> findAll();
```

Refer here for detail: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/155

Answer (score 2):

This is common issue: hitting annotation limits. People working with  annotations often seek to "ban" XML (or other file type) configuration.

I fear you cannot reuse annotations. Your choice is then limited to code duplication or partial use of XML, at least for *resultMap* declarations, referencing them by @ResultMap("resultMapId").

(Mybatis) XML elements are loaded into a registry, whereas annotations (generally) can be seen as parts of the method declaration.
Annotations are designed to be bound to methods: no id to reference, unlike in XML.